# wireless does not appear after instal of ubuntu on laptop ?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I need help the wireless does not work on my dell studio 1535 laptop. I have a Broadcom corporation BCM4322. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this using terminal

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It may work.
More information check this [WifiTroubleshootGuide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide)

You may need to install drivers . I found a good discussion on [How to install BroadCom drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx)`